# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ChartType'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

html file

```
 <div style="width: 100%; display: block">
      <canvas
        *ngIf="loaded"
        baseChart
        [data]="barChartData"
        [labels]="barChartLabels"
        [options]="barChartOptions"
        [legend]="barChartLegend"
        [chartType]="barChartType"
        
      >
      </canvas>
    </div>
```

ts.file

```
 barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true
  };
  barChartLabels: string[] =[];
  barChartType: string = 'horizontalBar';
  barChartLegend: boolean = true;
  barChartData: any[] =[];
  loaded = false;

this.service.Salescount(form).subscribe((data) => {
      this.name = data.result;
      this.barChartLabels = this.name.map((item) => item.name);
      this.barChartData = this.name.map((item) => item.sales);
      this.loaded = true;
})
```

There are 4 values in barchart.labels and barchartdata. While running i m getting error as " Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ChartType'"

And also I have imported ChartModules in app.module.ts

Comment: Which version of chart.js are you using?

Comment: It appears that you are passing a string to a value which expects a CharType but is nowhere to be seen

Comment: i m using
 "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
  "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2"

Comment: I got the answer . I just changed chartType datatype from string to any .

Comment: @FazariaAsira any should be avoided as much as possible

Comment: Thank you @VimalPatel.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `barChartType` type from `string` to `ChartType` and import it from chart.js.

```
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you . finally this one is worked . I have another one problem that how to change y axis value in range of 2.5

Comment: Requesting you to please ask a new question with requirement and the issue you are facing.

Comment: Okay @Vimal Patel. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you change CharType datatype to any?